# Efficiency and Swift coding etiquettes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I had a few questions regarding what is right and what is wrong in terms of structuring a well coded application in XCode and Swift 2.

**Example:**
Is it okay to initialize Views and Fields as so in a class?

```
var name_field: UITextView?
var user_field: UITextView?
var email_field: UITextView?
var pass_field: UITextView?
```

And then customizing them in the viewdidload() or a func as so:

```
user_field = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(20, sub_pad_1, fixed_width,     fixed_height/2))
user_field!.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
user_field!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
user_field!.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No
user_field!.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
user_field!.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Default
user_field!.delegate = self
```

I feel the exclamation points and question marks add potential risk of memory leaks and simply inefficiency to the structure of the code. Is there a way around it, as the sole reason why I have variables defined in such a way is to add the flexibility of accessing the objects class-wide within all the functions.

Comment: At least variable names including underscores like yours do not conform to the Swift naming etiquette.

Comment: @vadian curious, why is camelcase preferred/stressed?

Comment: The most important reason is the interoperability with Objective-C

Comment: I'm afraid questions about coding etiquette and best practices are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they can only be answered based on personal opinion, not fact.

Comment: @JAL true, I felt I was more going along the lines if my coding practice is correct and AMomchilov understood my predicament correctly and answered it fully.

Comment: Right, but that doesn't mean that your question is on-topic for Stack Overflow, even if it was answered.  Please review the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), specifically [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Example: Is it okay to initialize Views and Fields as so in a class?

None of the examples given are **initialization** (aka **definition**). Those are all **declaration**. For example, `var name_field: UITextView?` declares "There will exist a variable named `name_field`, of type `Optional(UITextView)`. It does not initialize (or define) it to have any value.

> I feel the exclamation points and question marks add potential risk of memory leaks and simply inefficiency to the structure of the code.

Memory leaks are not the issue when it comes to force unwrapping (`!`). A memory leak occurs when an object persists in memory when no more references exist to it. It's memory that can't be accessed (thus, can't serve any useful purpose), but isn't freed. It's completely unrelated to force unwrapping.

In this case, there's no reason at all to have those fields be optional. Something like this should still work, so long as the values are all set in the initializer:

```
struct Example {

    var name_field: UITextView
    var user_field: UITextView
    var email_field: UITextView
    var pass_field: UITextView

    init() {
        user_field = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(20, sub_pad_1, fixed_width, fixed_height/2))
        user_field.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        user_field.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
        user_field.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No
        user_field.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
        user_field.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Default
        user_field.delegate = self

        name_field = something
        email_field= something
        pass_field= something
    }
}
```

There's an even better approach, that better encapsulates the `UITextView` instantiation:

```
struct Example {

    var name_field: UITextView
    var user_field: UITextView
    var email_field: UITextView
    var pass_field: UITextView

    init() {
        user_field = {
            let uitv = (frame: CGRectMake(20, sub_pad_1, fixed_width, fixed_height/2))
            uitv.textAlignment = .Center
            uitv.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
            uitv.autocorrectionType = .No
            uitv.keyboardType = .Default
            uitv.returnKeyType = .Default
            uitv.delegate = self

            return uitv
        }()

        name_field = something
        email_field= something
        pass_field= something
    }
}
```

## Other notes:

- Swift convention is to use `camelCaseNames`, rather than `snake_case_names`
- You don't need to state the enumeration type explicitly. The compiler can infer it. For example, `UIReturnKeyType.Default` can be just `.Default`
- Don't use `var` if you don't need immutability. Favor `let` wherever possible.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a better explanation of my own poor word choice. So structs are a good way of declaring and initializing fields?

Comment: Structs and classes both act the same in this regard, so it doesn't matter. A field can be non-optional so long as it's given an initializer in-line (e.g. `let x = 5`), or if it is defined in the initializer, such as what I show above.

Comment: whenever I call the struct throughout my app in multiple classes, will the init() always run first? or is that only once and then the variables are just accessible afterwards. Not sure if I am getting the fundamental thinking here straight

Comment: `init()` methods are *initializers*, or *constructors* as you may know them from other languages. For example, doing `String()` initializes a new string, calling an `init` method which takes no params. It is equivalent to: `String.init()`

Comment: You really need to read the language guide. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html There's a whole section on initialization: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203

Comment: So I would have to call "Example.init()" to execute the properties within the init() method. It would make sense to do so in the viewDidLoad? Edit: Thanks for the links, I will read through them.

Comment: or just `Example()`. `viewDidLoad` is called AFTER your view has already been instantiated for you. Read the language guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually make the properties implicitly unwrapped optionals.

```
var name_field: UITextView!
```

This was you will be able to use this property without the ! symbol.

```
user_field = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(20, sub_pad_1, fixed_width, fixed_height/2))
user_field.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
user_field.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
...
```

Have in mind that implicitly unwrapped optionals are only a good solution if this property will always have a value != nil. If somebody tries to use this property before it was initialised the result will be a runtime exception. That's why I would suggest to restrict its visibility by making it private.

Comment: This *works*, but it's really just a syntactic transformation that doesn't address the main issue (the abuse of force unwrapping).

Comment: UIKit was designed for Objective-C and not Swift. That's why sometimes you need to use force unwrapping with instance variables that you would otherwise initialise in the constructor or pass as an parameter of the constructor. I don't see any reason why force unwrapping might lead to a memory leak.